# NLP - speed up word similarity matchin

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

I am trying to find maximum similarity between two words in pandas dataframe. Here is my routine

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame({'word_1':['desk', 'lamp', 'read'], 'word_2':['call','game','cook']})

def max_similarity(row):
    word_1 = row['word_1']
    word_2 = row['word_2']

    ret_val = max([(wordnet.wup_similarity(syn_1, syn_2) or 0) for 
       syn_1, syn_2 in itertools.product(wordnet.synsets(word_1), wordnet.synsets(word_2))])

    return ret_val

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: max_similarity(x), axis= 1)
```

It works fine, but it is too slow. I am looking for a way to speed it up. `wordnet` takes majority of time Any suggestions? Cython? I open to using other packages such as `spacy`.

Comment: lolz...That piece of code looks familiar ;P

Comment: @alvas, yeap, I borrowed if from some other post from stackoverflow.com ;-). I guess it was yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you are open to use [spacy](https://spacy.io) as NLP library, lets consider a simple benchmark. We will use the brown news corpus to create somewhat arbitrary word pairs by dividing it in half.

```
from nltk.corpus import brown

brown_corpus = list(brown.words(categories='news'))
brown_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'word_1':brown_corpus[:len(brown_corpus)//2],
    'word_2': brown_corpus[len(brown_corpus)//2:]
})

len(brown_df)
50277
```

The cosine similarity of two tokens/documents can be computed with the [`Doc.similarity`](https://spacy.io/docs/api/doc#similarity) method.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

def spacy_max_similarity(row):
    word_1 = nlp(row['word_1'])
    word_2 = nlp(row['word_2'])
    
    return word_1.similarity(word_2)
```

Finally, apply both methods to the data frame:

```
nltk_similarity = %timeit -o brown_df.apply(nltk_max_similarity, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 59 s per loop

spacy_similarity = %timeit -o brown_df.apply(spacy_max_similarity, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 8.88 s per loop
```

Please note that NLTK and spacy use different techniques when it comes to measuring similarity. spacy uses word vectors that have been pretrained with a word2vec algorithm. From the [docs](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/word-vectors-similarities):

> **Using word vectors and semantic similarities**
>
> [...]
>
> The default English model installs vectors for one million vocabulary
> entries, using the 300-dimensional vectors trained on the Common Crawl
> corpus using the [GloVe](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) algorithm. The GloVe common crawl vectors have
> become a de facto standard for practical NLP.

[image: nltk word similarity vs. spacy]

Comment: Interesting! Word similarity in `spacy` and Synset similarity in `nltk` is theoretically very different =)

Answer (score 2):

One way to make it faster is to store word-pair similarities. Then in case of repetition, avoid running the search function in the loop.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame({'word_1':['desk', 'lamp', 'read'], 'word_2':['call','game','cook']})

word_similarities = dict()
def max_similarity(row):
    word_1 = row['word_1']
    word_2 = row['word_2']

    key = tuple(sorted([word_1, word_2])) # symmetric measure :)

    if key not in word_similarities:
        word_similarities[key] = max([
            (wordnet.wup_similarity(syn_1, syn_2) or 0)
            for syn_1, syn_2 in itertools.product(wordnet.synsets(word_1), wordnet.synsets(word_2))
        ])

    return word_similarities[key]

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: max_similarity(x), axis= 1)
```